# Inverse normal CDF formula

Tags: normal-distribution, inverse

Why there is no formula for the inverse normal cumulative function?

It has been a while since I studied math so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no simple formula for the normal cumulative distribution function or for $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-y^2}\, dy$ either

Comment: @Henry Why is that so? What is the main reason? E.g for logistic function there is inverse function formula but not for normal function?

Comment: There is not a simple explanation.  Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29 to start, or https://web.archive.org/web/20100613092052/http://claymath.org/programs/outreach/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf for more detail